# debian- [ERROR] MySQL server not working "Unit mysql.service entered failed state."

Tags: mysql, debian, joomla, bitnami

This my first time setting a MySQL server on debian. I was trying to install Joomla! using this tutorial: [docs.joomla.org/Installing_Joomla_on_Debian_Linux](https://docs.joomla.org/Installing_Joomla_on_Debian_Linux)

I ended up installing [bitnami](/questions/tagged/bitnami) and everything went fine until the demo ended. Since then for some reason mysql stopped working.

I did quite a mess there trying to fix the issue by myself so i figured i would ask for some help.

Also I got the error `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` for a while and it changed when edited `my.cnf` that way. (socket used to be at `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/`)

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

So here is the error i got (details with systemctl status mysql.service):

```
    mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since lun. 2016-08-22 11:09:35 CEST; 2s ago
  Process: 25694 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Control: 25698 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─25698 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And the "`journalctl -xn`" result:

```
    -- Logs begin at lun. 2016-08-22 10:15:10 CEST, end at lun. 2016-08-22 11:11:03 CEST. --
août 22 11:10:55 tarte systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
août 22 11:10:58 tarte systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
août 22 11:10:58 tarte systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: L'unité (unit) mysql.service a échoué
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
```

Finally here is my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (part of it at least):

```
 The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password       = your_password
port            = 3306
socket          = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
```

I have no clue has what i should do now, ask for more info if necessary. Be specific please since i have a hard time understanding all this.

Comment: What does the MySQL log say? It could be at `/var/log/mysql*.log` or `/var/log/daemon.log`. Daemon log contains also messages from other system daemons, so you have to search a bit.

Comment: `Error: trying to open the tablespace file './phpmyadmin/pma__savedsearches.ibd'! Have you moved InnoDB .ibd files around without using the commands DISCARD TABLESPACE and IMPORT TABLESPACE? It is also possible that this is a temporary table #sql..., and MySQL removed the .ibd file for this.
Operating system error number 2 in a file operation. The error means the system cannot find the path specified.If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.`

Well didn't move those files, gonna explore a link they gave me. (on mysql.com)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned

> I ended up installing Bitnami and everything went fine until the demo ended. Since then for some reason mysql stopped working.

I don't understand what you mean with that. Maybe you launched a Demo Server in the Cloud and you can't connect it anymore since the Demo expired and it's not available anymore.

I see that you are mixing `/opt/lampp/var/...` references with `/var/...`. The Bitnami Stacks are self-contained. That means that if you install the Bitnami Stack under `/opt/lampp/` everything you need is under that directory (php, Apache, MySQL, etc.). However you are trying to use components installed in your system to connect the MySQL installed in the Bitnami Stack.

I recommend you to take a look at [this guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/mysql/) to learn how to use the MySQL installed on a Bitnami Stack.